# Accessing NSDictionary values Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

My Nsdictionary looks like this.

```
{
 thread = "{
 \"uuid\": \"e9290344dee38c42782\",
 \"site_full\": \"www.independent.co.uk\",
 \"main_image\":\"http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article10498560.ece/binary/original/39-tea-party-ap.jpg\"
 }";
}  

[newDict valueForKeyPath:@"thread.main_image"];
```

I am trying to access it like that but it I can get all the other values which are outside the thread but cant the nested values in the thread.Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
      for (int i=0;i < [responseObject count];i++) {
                NSDictionary* newDict = (NSDictionary*)responseObject[i];

                    if ([(NSString*)[newDict valueForKey:@"title"]  isEqualToString: @""] || [newDict valueForKey:@"title"]== Nil)  {
                        NSLog(@"Image or Title Text is null");
                    }
                    else{
                    NewsFeed* newsData = [NewsFeed new];
                    newsData.newsSource = [newDict valueForKeyPath:@"thread.site"];
                    newsData.newsImageLink = [newDict valueForKeyPath:@"thread.main_image"];
              //these three work fine
                    newsData.newsTitle = [newDict valueForKeyPath:@"title"];
                    newsData.newsText = [newDict valueForKeyPath:@"text"];
                    newsData.newsDate = [newDict valueForKeyPath:@"published"]; 
              //
                    NSLog(@"news Source :: %@ \n and news ImageLink:: %@ \n news Title %@  \nnews Text:: %@ \n news Date::  %@  ",newsData.newsSource,newsData.newsImageLink,newsData.newsTitle,newsData.newsText,newsData.newsDate);
                    [NewsData addObject:newsData];
                    }


        }
```

Comment: Please show what code you have tried, and how it was deficient.

Comment: I have added the code and the response is coming in form of an array..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the object stored at the indexed subscript `"thread"` is *not* an `NSDictionary` as assumed, but rather it appears to be an instance of `NSString`.

It's subtle, but look at the printed value of the object at key `"thread"` in the root-level dictionary:

```
This is an NSDictionary with one key: "thread"
|
|         This is an NSString object, see the quotes (")?
|         |
V         |                     Notice that these other keys/values have their quotes (") escaped with backslash?
{         V                     |
 thread = "{                    V
 \"uuid\": \"e9290344dee38c42782\",
 \"site_full\": \"www.independent.co.uk\",
 \"main_image\":\"http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article10498560.ece/binary/original/39-tea-party-ap.jpg\"
 }";
} ^
  |
  Here is the end of the NSString, again we see quotes (")
```

Assuming this is indeed the problem, you'll need to convert the string to an actual dictionary, which you should be able to easily do [using JSON serialization which this question/answer should help guide you to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18736505/868193)

Once this problem has been corrected, your use of `valueForKeyPath:` should be correct and should immediately start working.

Comment: Just checked it out...Indeed that was the problem and the suggested link's  solution was exactly what i wanted..Thanks alot man..

Answer (score 1):

Try this modern objective-C code:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"thread" : @{@"uuid" : @"e9290344dee38c42782", @"site_full" : @"www.independent.co.uk", @"main_image" : @"http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article10498560.ece/binary/original/39-tea-party-ap.jpg"}};
NSLog(@"Image = %@", myDict[@"thread"][@"main_image"]);
```

**EDIT:** After OP response attaching debugger screenshot:

[image]

Comment: In debugginng po newDict[@"thread"] if i do this,It lists all the keys and its values but when i do this po myDict[@"thread"][@"main_image"]it gives this error error: warning: couldn't get cmd pointer (substituting NULL): no variable named '_cmd' found in this frame
Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: This works like a charm for me. See the attached screenshot from my debugger. I am using Xcode 7.

Comment: As Thuggish pointed out above, looks like your are not using the real dictionary and that is why you are not able to see it working. If you try with my sample dictionary, it should work. So crux here is check your incoming data & get it corrected to right dictionary.

Comment: yup that was the problem..thanks for the help people..:)